# Whats wrong with this URLRequest or Loader?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have the following code:

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID.text);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = "URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES";
myLoader.load(myRequest);
writeText(myLoader.data);
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(myLoader.data);
writeText(vars.peerID);
```

And the `get_peerID.php?` Gets displays:

```
peerID=5a00d01af308bb4261198d92a89b939979e7ea260a3ead7d49a9b6bdd0492b72
```

However, `writeText(vars.peerID)` always displays `null`. I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: check to see if there is anything in `myID.text`

Comment: Yes, it has a value. Good idea though. Thanks.

Comment: You need to attach a listener to the Loader and then check the data.  She's asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class is asynchronous.  To quote the docs:

> A URLLoader object downloads all of
>   the data from a URL before making it
>   available to code in the applications.
>   It sends out notifications about the
>   progress of the download, which you
>   can monitor through the bytesLoaded
>   and bytesTotal properties, as well as
>   through dispatched events.

So, the only way that vars.peerID will work directly after calling the URLLoader.load method is if your network has zero latency and your server side processing has a 0 execution time.  Both, are extremely unlikely.

Instead you should listen to the [complete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3acomplete) event.

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID.text);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = "URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES";
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
myLoader.load(myRequest);
```

then somewhere later in code, something like this:

```
public function onComplete(event:Event):void{
 writeText(myLoader.data);
 var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(myLoader.data);
 writeText(vars.peerID);
}
```